# 冬に助けられたし　（Who was?)

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

> 「早く起きるべし」
>
> 「んー？……まだ、６時じゃないか。外も暗いし」
>
> 「それでも、冬の朝だし」
>
> 「――って、ちょおおおお、なにしてんの！？寒い寒い！」
>
> 「空気の入れ換え。よどんだアレ臭い部屋も、冬の朝の空気が清めてくれる的なアレ」
>
> 「変に濁すな。とゆーか、臭くない……はず」
>
> 「くんくん…………**冬に助けられたし**」
>
> 「匂いを嗅いだうえに失礼な」
>
> まだこの部屋ではソロプレイをしてないので大丈夫なはずだが……。

Who exactly is she referring to when she says 冬に助けられたし?

It's either him or her.

It could be her in the sense that she doesn't have to, well, smell his smell.

It could be him since she doesn't know whether his room smells because she opened the door.

I think it's the second one based on context(previous sentence), but I'm not sure. Can anyone clarify which one they believe it is?

Answer (score 3):

I think 冬に助けられたし in this sentence means "This(His) room didn't smell because the winter morning air cleaned up the air of his room", that is to say, "he was helped by winter".